# Split results from database to several lines

Tags: c#, sql

I am learning to display data from the database using C#. I want to arrange the data with a more tidy design. I want to print out result like this:

[image]

Here is the code I have tried:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.120.56;Initial Catalog=EDI;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select TOP 2 * FROM table ", con);
        con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        string a = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\t";
        Console.Write(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having now?

Comment: ok, well. other than you only select 2 items, what do you feel is wrong with your code?

Comment: the data not tidy like stick together than some spacing very far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is add newline characters after each row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        string a = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\t";
        Console.Write(a);
    }
    Console.Write("\n\r");
}
```

Comment: or simply [`Console.WriteLine();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdf6yhx5(v=vs.110).aspx), then you don't need to remember that it's  `"\r\n"` not `"\n\r"`

Answer (score 1):

Using `Linq`.

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => String.Join("\t", row.ItemArray));

foreach(string row in rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a string to hold you string you want to build and the display it

```
string a = "";

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            a += dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\t";
        }
         a += "\n";
    }

Console.Writeline(a);
```